# How to actually view own unpublished content in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

According to the documentation at http://drupal.org/node/1106606 "By enabling 'View own unpublished content', you grant users access to their own unpublished content." Great, but then how can a user with that permission actually find her own unpublished content?

I have a Drupal 7 site and I created a user, then gave 'Content Editor' and 'Blogger' roles to it. I checked the permissions and those roles have 'View own unpublished content' set. Along with permissions such as 'View the administrative dashboard'. Please see the following screen shots:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/64416865@N00/5736169925/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/64416865@N00/5736720168/

However the user that has only 'Content Editor' + 'Blogger' roles cannot see any link on which she can click to see her unpublished content. I can log in as an administrator, then I see the administrative overlay, I can see the 'Find content' link on top, I can visit /admin/content. But that other user cannot see that administrative overlay and when tries to visit /admin/content she receives "Access denied You are not authorized to access this page." message.

Am I missing some permissions? Or did I forget some other thing? How can a non-admin user with 'View own unpublished content' permission set actually see the list of her unpublished content items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Based on some suggestions and realising the security implications of my first solution I undid it, installed the Views and created a view which shows unpublished blog entries filtered by author = current user. I think this is much more compatible with the 'Drupal way'.

<strike>Apparently one also needs to set 'Access the content overview page' permission! So that the user can access admin/content.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

Drupal doesn't create a list of unpublished content by default; therefore, there is no such listing.  If you don't want to give admin permissions to the content listing for your Content Editor and Blogger users, you can try creating a View to list all the user's unpublished content and make the view available to the user so that he/she can see the list.